# Entity Framework 6 Unable to retrive metadata

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF 6 pre-3.

Product model:

```
namespace ProductStore.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal ActualCost { get; set; }
    }
```

}

When I created a controller, I get the following error:

```
Unable to retrieve metadata for 'ProductStore.Models.Project'. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'.
```

The Context is:

```
namespace ProductStore.Models
{
    public class OrdersContext : DbContext
    {
        public OrdersContext()
            : base("name=OrdersContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My connection string is :

```
<add name="OrdersContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Orders.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Do you also have reference to `System.Data.Entity`? Is it a new project or did you use existing project to upgrade to EF6?

Comment: Yes I have it. It is a new project.

Comment: Start by removing all references to old System.Data.Entity.dll. EF6 is out-of-band release and it contains everything from System.Data.Entity.

Comment: I remove the System.Data.Entity from reference, it still fail to generate a controller.

Comment: @Alvin You can approve an answer so that other would prefer it

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework 6 does not support scaffolding. Using NuGet package manager console to get Entity Framework 5 will fix this issue. You will then be able to create your controller with CRUD actions.
[Here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/5.0.0) is a link to NuGet EF5.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested, Entity Framework 6 cannot do scaffolding yet.

Comment: ASP.NET Scaffolding is a code generation framework for ASP.NET Web applications. 

 
http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/aspnet-scaffolding-overview

Answer (score 0):

I have tested too, I think Entity FrameWork 6 not Stable
.you can rebuild project, use Nuget install Entity FrameWork 5.

Answer (score 0):

Update EF to version 6.0.1 then rebuild your solution. Should work after that.